# Grails Export Plugin - Embed Image

Tags: grails

I've got the grails export plugin working nicely but is there any way of embedding an image in the produced pdf report? I cant find an obvious way of doing it :(

many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Why would you require to put an image when export plugin only talks about domain object. If you are looking for generating report which has images and other html stuff, I think itext library is the way forward.

Thanks, KJ

Comment: Would just like to put a standard image in the header for all generated output, e.g. a company logo. I can include header text that isn't part of the domain object, but not images yet. Thanks

Comment: Yeah in that case I dont think that export plugin is your cup of tea. Try using itext library.